# If $x^3-3y^2x \ge 3x^2y-y^3$ and $x+y=-1$ is a line segment, find the length of this line segment.

Tags: analytic-geometry, problem-solving

If the formulas $x^3-3y^2x \ge 3x^2y-y^3$ and $x+y=-1$ together define a line segment, find the length of this line segment.

I've tried setting $x=-(1+y)$, substituting that into the first equation and solving it when equality holds, and then finding the length of the line segment which I got as $\sqrt{30}/6$. This is very messy and I'm sure that there is a better approach.

Comment: Is there a neat solution to this problem using complex numbers and the roots of unity? This problem appears in Zeitz's Art and Craft of Problem Solving as question 4.2.28, under the topic of complex numbers.

Answer (score 8):

Note that 
$$\begin{align}&x^3-3y^2x\ge 3x^2y-y^3\\\\&\iff (x^3+y^3)-3xy(x+y)\ge 0\\\\&\iff (x+y)(x^2-xy+y^2)-3xy(x+y)\ge 0\\\\&\iff (x+y)((x+y)^2-3xy)-3xy(x+y)\ge 0\end{align}$$

Since $x+y=-1$, we get
$$(-1)((-1)^2-3xy)-3xy(-1)\ge 0,$$
i.e.
$$xy\ge \frac 16,$$
i.e.
$$x(-x-1)\ge\frac 16,$$
i.e.
$$(x_{\text{min}}=)\ \frac{-3-\sqrt 3}{6}\le x\le \frac{-3+\sqrt 3}{6}\ (=x_{\text{max}})$$

Therefore, the answer is
$$\sqrt{(x_{\text{max}}-x_{\text{min}})^2+((-x_{\text{max}}-1)-(-x_{\text{min}}-1))^2}=\sqrt 2\ |x_{\text{max}}-x_{\text{min}}|=\color{red}{\frac{\sqrt 6}{3}}$$

Answer (score 1):

The segment $\sigma$ in question is formed the points on the line $\ell:\ x+y=-1$ satisfying
$$(x+y)^3-6xy(x+y)\geq0\ ,$$
which is the same thing as the points on $\ell$ satisfying $6xy\geq1$. For these points we also have
$$(x-y)^2=(x+y)^2-4xy\leq1-{2\over3}\ ,$$
hence $|x-y|\leq{1\over\sqrt{3}}$. The two lines $y=x\pm{1\over\sqrt{3}}$ intersect $\ell$ orthogonally, and are at distance ${1\over\sqrt{2}}\cdot{2\over\sqrt{3}}={\sqrt{6}\over3}$ of each other. It follows that this distance is then also the length of $\sigma$.