# Find length of line segment using complex numbers/roots of unity approach

Tags: complex-numbers, roots-of-unity

Is there a nice solution using complex numbers/roots of unity for the following question:

> The set of points that satisfy both $x^3-3y^2x\ge 3x^2y-y^3$ and $x+y=-1$ is a line segment. Find the length of this line segment.

This question was posted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2024025/168053) and some nice solutions were provided using conventional algebra.

The question here is whether there is a solution which uses the complex numbers/roots of unity approach, as this question was found in Zeitz's *The Art and Craft of Problem Solving* under the section on this topic.

Comment: $(x-yi)^3=x^3-3x^2yi-3xy^2+y^3i$ might be useful.

Comment: @GerryMyerson - Thanks, very useful comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Gerry Myerson's comment, we note that the inequality is

$$ \Re(( x-\mathrm i y)^3) + \Im ((x-\mathrm i y)^3) > 0$$
or equivalently

$$ \Re ((x+\mathrm i y)^3 ) > \Im((x+\mathrm i y)^3).$$
writing $x+\mathrm i y = r e^{\mathrm i \theta}$, we need to know when

$$ r^3 cos(3\theta) > r^3 \sin(3\theta).$$
Let me skip the high school trigonometry work, this gives you 3 regions of angles

$$ \theta \in \left(\frac{-\pi}4, \frac{\pi}{12}\right) + \frac{2k\pi}3, \quad k = 0,1,2.$$

Draw a graph:
[image: graph of angles and x+y=-1 line]
now its clear we just need to find these 2 intersection points. I'll leave that part to you.

Comment: Thanks. Very nice answer. (+1)

Comment: @hypergeometric You're welcome. PS one doesn't need to resort to trig if one is comfortable working with arguments of complex numbers and reasoning with the cube root, the 3 branches give 3 different regions...but of course the high school route is more elementary